# How to add custom header and footer in laravel tcpdf?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, laravel-5.1, tcpdf, makepdf

How can I add custom header and footer text in tcpdf using laravel controller

Following the [TCPDF doc](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_001/) I can create a pdf file fine. but when I want to add custom footer text I didn't do that. 
This is the  [Controller](https://gist.github.com/infoshahin/59593820986bf67c40ccfceeb070ccd7).

How can I add custom footer in tcpdf or you have any solution for the custom footer any other package which I will use custom footer easily please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem using mPdf instead of tcpdf. Using mPdf I just called SetFooter() function.

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();

$mpdf->Bookmark('Start of the document');

$mpdf->WriteHTML('<div>This is body text </div>');
$mpdf->SetFooter('<div>This is custom footer!</div>');

$mpdf->Output();
```

Now custom footer worked for me!